# fadeOut/In function produces a blink

Tags: jquery, html

I am using title values to show/hide some divs when buttons are clicked.
First button will show only the divs with **ab** value and the second one will show all of the divs. Everything (kinda) works but when showing all the divs, the fadeOut/In produces a nasty blink...(you can see it in this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/3odxseoh/))

HTML

```
<button id="ab">AB</button>
<button id="all">ALL</button>
<hr>
<div class="work" title="ab">AB</div>
<div class="work" title="dc">DC</div>
<div class="work" title="ab">AB</div>
<div class="work" title="dc">DC</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$( "#ab" ).click(function(){
    $( ".work" ).fadeOut(400);    
    $( ".work[title *='ab']" ).fadeIn(400);
});

$('#all').click(function(){
    $( ".work[title *='ab']" ).fadeOut(400);
    $( ".work" ).fadeIn(400);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the fadeOut and fadeIn are executing at the same time (they are asynchronous), which usually leads to unexpected and unattractive results. Both functions provide optional callbacks, which you should utilize so that the fadeIn occurs after the fadeOut is complete.

Example:

```
$( "#ab" ).click(function(){
    $( ".work" ).fadeOut(400, function(){
       // This anonymous function executes after fadeOut has finished.  It is provided
       // as a callback to fadeOut.
       $( ".work[title *='ab']" ).fadeIn(400);
    });    

});
```